# Error in terraform module mainly to do with log analytics

Tags: terraform

I am in the process of learning TF, and on the subject of modules, at the same time I have decided to only create resources on my Azure account using TF as a way to accelerate my learning. To this note, I found this gitbub repo https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-virtual-machine

I have been following the contents and trying to reproduce on my test system, I have tried to contact the author to no avail and felt I have already wasted 2 weeks trying to fix the problem, let me ask on here for help.

**My setup.**

Pulled the code from the repo onto my laptop.
logged onto my Azure account from a powershell console.
created a folder called create_vm
and in that folder
On my main.tf file, I have the following. This is a linux example, but I had the same issues with a windows example also.

```
# Azurerm provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Creates a new resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test_build" {
  name     = "testBuild"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# Creates a new network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }
}

# Creates a new la workspace
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "la" {
  name                = "loganalytics-we-sharedtest2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
}

module "virtual-machine" {
  source  = "kumarvna/virtual-machine/azurerm"
  version = "2.3.0"

  # Resource Group, location, VNet and Subnet details
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
  location             = "westeurope"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  subnet_name          = "subnet1"
  virtual_machine_name = "vm-linux"

  # This module support multiple Pre-Defined Linux and Windows Distributions.
  # Check the README.md file for more pre-defined images for Ubuntu, Centos, RedHat.
  # Please make sure to use gen2 images supported VM sizes if you use gen2 distributions
  # Specify `disable_password_authentication = false` to create random admin password
  # Specify a valid password with `admin_password` argument to use your own password 
  # To generate SSH key pair, specify `generate_admin_ssh_key = true`
  # To use existing key pair, specify `admin_ssh_key_data` to a valid SSH public key path.  
  os_flavor               = "linux"
  linux_distribution_name = "ubuntu2004"
  virtual_machine_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  generate_admin_ssh_key  = true
  instances_count         = 2

  # Proxymity placement group, Availability Set and adding Public IP to VM's are optional.
  # remove these argument from module if you dont want to use it.  
  enable_proximity_placement_group = true
  enable_vm_availability_set       = true
  enable_public_ip_address         = true

  # Network Seurity group port allow definitions for each Virtual Machine
  # NSG association to be added automatically for all network interfaces.
  # Remove this NSG rules block, if `existing_network_security_group_id` is specified
  nsg_inbound_rules = [
    {
      name                   = "ssh"
      destination_port_range = "22"
      source_address_prefix  = "*"
    },
    {
      name                   = "http"
      destination_port_range = "80"
      source_address_prefix  = "*"
    },
  ]

  # Boot diagnostics to troubleshoot virtual machines, by default uses managed 
  # To use custom storage account, specify `storage_account_name` with a valid name
  # Passing a `null` value will utilize a Managed Storage Account to store Boot Diagnostics
  enable_boot_diagnostics = true

  # Attach a managed data disk to a Windows/Linux VM's. Possible Storage account type are: 
  # `Standard_LRS`, `StandardSSD_ZRS`, `Premium_LRS`, `Premium_ZRS`, `StandardSSD_LRS`
  # or `UltraSSD_LRS` (UltraSSD_LRS only available in a region that support availability zones)
  # Initialize a new data disk - you need to connect to the VM and run diskmanagemnet or fdisk
  data_disks = [
    {
      name                 = "disk1"
      disk_size_gb         = 100
      storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    },
    {
      name                 = "disk2"
      disk_size_gb         = 200
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }
  ]

  # (Optional) To enable Azure Monitoring and install log analytics agents
  # (Optional) Specify `storage_account_name` to save monitoring logs to storage.   
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.id

  # Deploy log analytics agents to virtual machine. 
  # Log analytics workspace customer id and primary shared key required.
  deploy_log_analytics_agent                 = true
  log_analytics_customer_id                  = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.workspace_id
  log_analytics_workspace_primary_shared_key = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.primary_shared_key

  # Adding additional TAG's to your Azure resources
  tags = {
    ProjectName  = "demo-project"
    Env          = "dev"
    Owner        = "user@example.com"
    BusinessUnit = "CORP"
    ServiceClass = "Gold"
  }
}
```

on variables.tf.

```
variable "log_analytics_workspace_name" {
  description = "The name of log analytics workspace name"
  default     = null
}

variable "storage_account_name" {
  description = "The name of the hub storage account to store logs"
  default     = null
}
variable "create_resource_group" {
  description = "Whether to create resource group and use it for all networking resources"
  default     = true
}
```

Please note that I added the create_resource_group variable to try to resolve my issue to no avail.

I then run

terraform init
terraform plan

I get the following error with terraform plan

```
│ Error: Error: Log Analytics workspaces "loganalytics-we-sharedtest2" (Resource Group "rg-shared-westeurope-01") was not found
│
│   with data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example,
│   on main.tf line 6, in data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example":
│    6: data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Error: Resource Group "rg-shared-westeurope-01" was not found
│
│   with module.virtual-machine.data.azurerm_resource_group.rg,
│   on .terraform\modules\virtual-machine\main.tf line 27, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg":
│   27: data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
│
```

**What have I done ?**

- Looked through the code to see what I am missing.
- Added the variable at the top. Tried to contact the author to no
  avail.
- Tried to use an   existing resource group, I feel this defeats the
  purpose of having a    variable that asks if a new resource group can
  be created in case it    doesn't already exist.

**What else is confusing ?**

I initially had another folder for modules, i later came to realise that the module is a public one being pulled down whenever I ran terraform init, now is there a way to have this as a localised module ?

I have made the changes recommended by the answer below, however in order not to turn the question into a long winded one, I have placed the error that I got below.

```
│ Error: Error: Subnet: (Name "subnet1" / Virtual Network Name "testBuild_vnet" / Resource Group "testBuild") was not found
│
│   with module.virtual-machine.data.azurerm_subnet.snet,
│   on .terraform\modules\virtual-machine\main.tf line 36, in data "azurerm_subnet" "snet":
│   36: data "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on .terraform\modules\virtual-machine\main.tf line 443, in resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "nsg":
│  443:   count                      = var.existing_network_security_group_id == null && var.log_analytics_workspace_id != null ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Where are you running init from, the directory where `main.tf` and other terraform files are located or from the `modules` directory? I have taken a look at the examples provided in the repo and in the example the resource group with the same name from the error is used.

Comment: Why is the resource group name in the code different from the one in the error message?

Comment: @learner where does `testBuild_vnet` in your first error come from? In my answer the vnet was called `example-network`.

Comment: @Sebastian The reason i changed it is that i got the error, `Error: Error: Virtual Network: (Name "example-network" / Resource Group "testBuild") was not found` and `Error: Invalid count argument on .terraform\modules\virtual-machine\main.tf line 443, in resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "nsg":
│  443:   count                      = var.existing_network_security_group_id == null && var.log_analytics_workspace_id != null ? 1 : 0` . This was why i changed it to a resource group that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the misunderstanding is that you think the module **creates** a resource group, but that is not the case. This module expects an already existing resource group as `var.resource_group_name` (same goes for the input variables `virtual_network_name`, `subnet_name` and `log_analytics_workspace_id`).

The main difference between the `resource_` and `data_` prefix is that data sources are read-only and "only" fetch already existing infrastructure for further use:

> Data sources allow Terraform to use information defined outside of
> Terraform, defined by another separate Terraform configuration, or
> modified by functions.

https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources

So in your case it should work like (not tested):

```
# Azurerm provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Creates a new resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test_build" {
  name     = "testBuild"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# Creates a new network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }
}

# Creates a new la workspace
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "la" {
  name                = "loganalytics-we-sharedtest2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
}

module "virtual-machine" {
  source  = "kumarvna/virtual-machine/azurerm"
  version = "2.3.0"

  # Resource Group, location, VNet and Subnet details
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test_build.name
  location             = "westeurope"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  subnet_name          = "subnet1"
  virtual_machine_name = "vm-linux"

  # This module support multiple Pre-Defined Linux and Windows Distributions.
  # Check the README.md file for more pre-defined images for Ubuntu, Centos, RedHat.
  # Please make sure to use gen2 images supported VM sizes if you use gen2 distributions
  # Specify `disable_password_authentication = false` to create random admin password
  # Specify a valid password with `admin_password` argument to use your own password 
  # To generate SSH key pair, specify `generate_admin_ssh_key = true`
  # To use existing key pair, specify `admin_ssh_key_data` to a valid SSH public key path.  
  os_flavor               = "linux"
  linux_distribution_name = "ubuntu2004"
  virtual_machine_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  generate_admin_ssh_key  = true
  instances_count         = 2

  # Proxymity placement group, Availability Set and adding Public IP to VM's are optional.
  # remove these argument from module if you dont want to use it.  
  enable_proximity_placement_group = true
  enable_vm_availability_set       = true
  enable_public_ip_address         = true

  # Network Seurity group port allow definitions for each Virtual Machine
  # NSG association to be added automatically for all network interfaces.
  # Remove this NSG rules block, if `existing_network_security_group_id` is specified
  nsg_inbound_rules = [
    {
      name                   = "ssh"
      destination_port_range = "22"
      source_address_prefix  = "*"
    },
    {
      name                   = "http"
      destination_port_range = "80"
      source_address_prefix  = "*"
    },
  ]

  # Boot diagnostics to troubleshoot virtual machines, by default uses managed 
  # To use custom storage account, specify `storage_account_name` with a valid name
  # Passing a `null` value will utilize a Managed Storage Account to store Boot Diagnostics
  enable_boot_diagnostics = true

  # Attach a managed data disk to a Windows/Linux VM's. Possible Storage account type are: 
  # `Standard_LRS`, `StandardSSD_ZRS`, `Premium_LRS`, `Premium_ZRS`, `StandardSSD_LRS`
  # or `UltraSSD_LRS` (UltraSSD_LRS only available in a region that support availability zones)
  # Initialize a new data disk - you need to connect to the VM and run diskmanagemnet or fdisk
  data_disks = [
    {
      name                 = "disk1"
      disk_size_gb         = 100
      storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    },
    {
      name                 = "disk2"
      disk_size_gb         = 200
      storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }
  ]

  # (Optional) To enable Azure Monitoring and install log analytics agents
  # (Optional) Specify `storage_account_name` to save monitoring logs to storage.   
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.id

  # Deploy log analytics agents to virtual machine. 
  # Log analytics workspace customer id and primary shared key required.
  deploy_log_analytics_agent                 = true
  log_analytics_customer_id                  = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.workspace_id
  log_analytics_workspace_primary_shared_key = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.la.primary_shared_key

  # Adding additional TAG's to your Azure resources
  tags = {
    ProjectName  = "demo-project"
    Env          = "dev"
    Owner        = "user@example.com"
    BusinessUnit = "CORP"
    ServiceClass = "Gold"
  }
}
```

Just adding a new variable called `create_resource_group` will not do anything as long as there is no corresponding logic/code behind it.

Comment: I have now implemented the change and the output can be seen above, I have had to edit the question as I cannot place the output in the comments section.

Comment: I was also thinking, should I have imported my existing configuration in  azure ?